# how to find what is in data frame and not another in R

Tags: r, concatenation, match, anti-join

I have two data frames: codes and supply.
Codes (shown below) is comprised of four fields: state,codetype,code,codetitle
supply has 12 columns but three of them are state,codetype, and code

An example of this is below

```
    state     codetype    code    codetitle
      32          15     123456     Something
      32          15     123455     Something Else
      32          10     123455     Something Else
```

From there, I use the following code to concatenate the item

```
    supply1<- supply%>%mutate(supply1= paste0(state,codetype,code))
    codes1<- codes%>%mutate(codes1= paste0(state,codetype,code))
```

My question is how do I find out what combinations of state,codetype,code are in supply1 but not codes1. I would use excel and the match function to do this but there are 1.9 million rows and that exceeds the capacity of Excel.

Have looked at documentation about antijoin. However, being that there is no common field such as ID, getting a bit confused.

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for an "anti join". There is a function called `anti_join` in the `dplyr` package. Alternatively, you can just use `setdiff(supply1$supply1, codes1$codes1)` on the vectors you just created.

Comment: @Vincent is right initially (`anti_join`), though `setdiff` will work if you're judging based on one column only. Try `anti_join(supply1, codes1, by = c("state", "codetype", "code"))`. It's feasible in base R using `merge`, though it requires an extra step (and a temp column).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### tidyverse

```r
library(dplyr)
anti_join(supply, codes, by = c("state", "codetype", "code"))
#   state codetype   code   codetitle
# 1    34       15 123459 Something_4
```

### base R

```r
codes$code_rn <- seq_len(nrow(codes))
supply$supply_rn <- seq_len(nrow(supply))
temp <- merge(codes, supply, by = c("state", "codetype", "code"))
temp
#   state codetype   code    codetitle.x code_rn codetitle.y supply_rn
# 1    32       15 123455 Something_Else       2 Something_3         2
# 2    32       15 123456      Something       1 Something_2         1
supply[ !supply$supply_rn %in% temp$supply_rn, ]
#   state codetype   code   codetitle supply_rn
# 3    34       15 123459 Something_4         3
```

(and some column clean-up)

### alternative base R

This is effectively what you were starting with:

```r
supply_id <- with(supply, paste(state, codetype, code, sep = "|"))
supply_id
# [1] "32 15 123456" "32 15 123455" "34 15 123459"
codes_id <- with(codes, paste(state, codetype, code, sep = "|"))
codes_in
# [1] "32|15|123456" "32|15|123455" "32|10|123455"
supply[!supply_id %in% codes_id,]
#   state codetype   code   codetitle supply_rn
# 3    34       15 123459 Something_4         3
```

### data

```r
codes <- read.table(header = TRUE, text="
    state     codetype    code    codetitle
      32          15     123456     Something
      32          15     123455     Something_Else
      32          10     123455     Something_Else")
supply <- read.table(header = TRUE, text="
    state     codetype    code    codetitle
      32          15     123456     Something_2
      32          15     123455     Something_3
      34          15     123459     Something_4")
```

Comment: I kept the example small. In reality, my supply table has 234,966 rows. While the code operates with no errors, it says that I reached my max and that there are essentially 234,944 rows in the result set.

Comment: I understand. It might be preferable then to use the `paste0(..., sep="|")` option (some separation string) and use `!a %in%` b`. See my edit in 2 minutes

Answer (score 2):

With `data.table`, we do a join `on` the columns after converting the 'supply' to a `data.table` (`setDT`).  By negating (`!`), we check for the elements that are not matching in 'codes' dataset

```
library(data.table)
setDT(supply)[!codes, on = c("state", "codetype", "code")]
```

Comment: This worked. However, Is there information on how I understand/interpret the results?

Comment: @TimWilcox Thanks, I updated with some description.